# How to handle split screen mode in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, split-screen

I want to enable dual window mode in my app. I have a Huawei Honor 5x with Android 6.0.1 and EMUI 4.0.1. It has a split screen mode, but only a few apps can support this feature.

How can I include it in my app?

Comment: refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

Comment: Android itself did not have multi-window support in Android 6.0. You would be looking for Huawei-specific instructions.

Comment: android:resizeableActivity doesn't work at all.